# What could be causing TeXLive packages to update without explicit user intervention?

Tags: texlive, knitr, tlmgr

Up until now I was under the impression that TeXLive's packages only updated when you invoked `tlmgr update ...`.

But today I noticed, for the first time, that some other process is definitely updating TeXLive packages. But I have not been able to identify which. **So I'm looking for advice on how to determine  what is causing these updates, and possibly help on how to stop these auto-updates from happening.** More details below if you'd like to read on ;-)

**TLDR**: TeXLive packages auto-update on irregular intervals by some mysterious process. One of these updates left me with a broken install, and now I'd like to be able to disable any auto-updates of TeXLive.

I have installed TeXLive 2020 on Ubuntu 18.04.5. I also have an old 2019 installation still in place, but all paths are since long correctly set for TL2020. I installed and maintain TeXLive (in fact, the whole system) using Ansible (I haven't made those playbooks public yet because reasons, but if you think it helps trouble-shooting this issue, I'd be happy to share the relevant parts with you).

How do I know for sure that TeXLive's packages have been updated?
Well, after a recompilation of the exact same LaTeX document (on the same git commit, clean repo) suddenly failed the second time around with an error about `filehook-2019.sty not found`, which made no sense, I looked for any files in the TeXLive tree that had been updated recently (i.e., today) and found a bunch, most notably (showing a selection):

```
$ find /usr/local/texlive -newermt "2020-12-16"
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/latex/filehook
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/source/latex/filehook
/usr/local/texlive/2020/tlpkg/tlpobj/filehook.tlpobj
/usr/local/texlive/2020/tlpkg/backups/filehook.r56291.tar.lz4
/usr/local/texlive/2020/tlpkg/backups/...
```

The clincher was the contents of the `tlmgr.log` file (again, only showing select parts):

```
[Sun Nov 29 04:34:29 2020] update: bookcover (46410 -> 56947)
[Tue Dec 15 21:27:05 2020] update: beamer (55908 -> 57140)
[Tue Dec 15 23:11:08 2020] update: decision-table (56164 -> 57094)
[Tue Dec 15 23:11:08 2020] update: denisbdoc (55474 -> 56664)
[Wed Dec 16 02:41:56 2020] update: fgruler (42966 -> 56854)
[Wed Dec 16 02:41:57 2020] update: filehook (56291 -> 56479)
```

The timings of these updates suggests that they are unrelated to my activities (which involves running `latexmk`, `lualatex`, `knitr::knit()`). Also, it's not an update of *all available* TeXLive packages, just a small subset, which I could confirm by running `tlmgr update --self --all` myself a short while later, which updated around 100 packages and after which my LaTeX document compiled just fine again.

I have read the relevant parts of the [TeXLive](https://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/texlive-en/texlive-en.html) and [`tlmgr`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) documentation, but found
no mention of auto-updates.

On my machine, I have checked the user and system cron-jobs, and found nothing that pertains to tlmgr. I also checked the systemd jobs, ditto.

If by chance it's not `tlmgr` that's causing these updates, then what could it be? I also have R installed on this machine (I regularly knit Rnw/Rmd documents) which includes the [`tinytex` R package](https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/), which I know contains a [wrapper for `tlmgr`](https://rdrr.io/cran/tinytex/man/tlmgr.html). But unless these are being activated on some schedule, or are invoked when [`knitr::knit()`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/046ae373e674f2e47e4d83a19d61fe46ab9ca4b5/R/output.R) is called, I don't see how they are the culprits (also, I run knitr::knit() almost daily, and TeXLive package auto-updates appear to happen on much longer intervals as the log file shows).

Comment: I don't have R installed these days but if knitr starts with tinytex (minimal texlive) does it run tlmgr for you for latex packages that are referenced from R?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You put your finger on the point precisely. Problem is, I'm not sure. I skimmed the `knitr::knit()` source code, but I can't claim to follow along well enough to determine whether it's calling `tinytex::tlmgr()`.
And tinytex is a dependency of other R pkgs I require, so I can't simply uninstall it to try without it...

Comment: random google search shows up [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex-pkgs.html#ref-R-tinytex) which does indicate that tinytex can be configured to parse the log for missing packages and install them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I considered that, but that's installation of missing packages. That did not happen in my case

Comment: (Stupid comment system blocking edits... when I pressed enter by mistake earlier). @DavidCarlisle That did not happen in my case, it's only package *updates*. And as far as I know, tinytex does not do that. Assuming that conclusion is correct, that leaves `latexmk` and `tlmgr`. But I take it from your focus on the R tools that those tools are not known to auto-update TeXLive packages either, right? But I must admit that my initial suspicions veer towards the R toolset, too. There's been so much development there, some of it focussed on making the users life easier...

Comment: I just realised I forgot to include a another suspect in my original post: **RStudio Server**, which I have on this machine as well. That systemd job is running in the background all the time. Perhaps RStudio does TeXLive updates in the background? I'll investigate some more, any pointers anyone might have are still greatly appreciated. Will update here if I find something.

Comment: As a general suggestion: consider managing Texlive as a distinct (non-privileged) user. (I use `texlive:texlive`.) That way, a process initiated by your regular user *can't* touch the main installation (and `tlmgr` *can't* touch your home directory).

Comment: @cfr That's a good suggestion! For now, I will take a step-by-step approach, and test the tinytex option first. But thanks for planting this idea in my head :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When compiling `.Rnw` or `.Rmd` documents to PDF, the R function `tinytex::latexmk()` is called, which tries to install missing LaTeX packages by default. This behavior can be disabled via the option:

```r
options(tinytex.install_packages = FALSE)
```

Before trying to install missing LaTeX packages, it will try to run `tlmgr update --self --all`. This is most likely to be the cause of the problem you observed.

Comment: Thanks for that insight! I will set this option, as you suggested, and keep an eye on the `tlmgr.log` etc. to see if updates keep happening, and report back here in a few days with confirmation (although I don't expect any surprises, your explanation makes a lot of sense to me).

Comment: One month later, many LaTeX and R re-runs later, and the `tlmgr.log` has not been touched. This setting definitely works as intended :-) Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer.

Comment: Could you guide exactly Yihui how to apply that option you specified please? I am trying to apply it via
```
tinytex::latexmk(file="myfile.Rmd", options(tinytex.install_packages = FALSE))
```
but it fails because I need a .tex rather than .Rmd. But I need it to work to render to generate the .tex, so I am stuck. Thanks for all your work on TinyTeX (and remark!), and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Notches This option is meant to be set in either a code chunk of your input document, or your `.Rprofile` (`file.edit('~/.Rprofile')`). The former setting only applies to that document, and the latter applies to any documents on your computer. It depends on whether you want to set the option locally or globally.

Comment: @YihuiXie I'm wondering if turning off above option would also disable automatic package updates? Or, is there a way to disable running `tlmgr update --self --all`?

Comment: @MatthewSon There isn't, but I think I can provide an option for that. Please feel free to file a feature request to https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex/issues. Thanks!